# elasticsearch - can't access localhost:9200 via curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I start `elasticsearch` server and want to access `localhost:9200` via curl.

Here is my try:

`curl -u elastic:H5VzhJP0txg4Lm9EMSZp localhost:9200`

`curl -u elastic:H5VzhJP0txg4Lm9EMSZp http://localhost:9200`

`curl -u elastic:H5VzhJP0txg4Lm9EMSZp http://127.0.0.1:9200`

`curl -XGET -u elastic:H5VzhJP0txg4Lm9EMSZp http://localhost:9200`

`curl -XGET -u elastic:H5VzhJP0txg4Lm9EMSZp -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:9200'`

All of them give me the result: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

But, I can access `localhost:9200` via browser.

here is my `elasticsearch` version:

```
☁  kibana-research [master] ⚡  elasticsearch --version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory

Version: 6.2.4, Build: ccec39f/2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z, JVM: 1.8.0_171
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is the `proxy`

Here is my config in `~/.zshrc` file

```
 98 # proxy list
 99 alias proxy='export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1086'
100 alias unproxy='unset all_proxy'
```

when I run `unproxy` in terminal, that means I don't use proxy server.

Then, it works fine.

```
☁  kibana-research [master] ⚡  curl -u elastic:H5VzhJP0txg4Lm9EMSZp localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "KBgeNNv",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_ldu020",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Src22ahwTYy9jVthB8w0DQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.4",
    "build_hash" : "ccec39f",
    "build_date" : "2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
curl 'username:password@localhost:9200'
curl 'username:password@localhost:9200' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```